# Allow user to crop an image without resizing in android app

Tags: android, android-intent, crop

I have this code for cropping an image:

```
Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    //indicate image type and Uri
cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
    //set crop properties
cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    //indicate aspect of desired crop
cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    //indicate output X and Y
cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);

    //start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
```

But I don't want to let user to change the size of cropper. I want user to just move cropper rectangle over image and crop the predefined size (width x height) of image.

Comment: There is no `CROP` `Intent` in Android: http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html

Comment: I have read this, but still I want to use it but with disabled resizing.